# Inkscape: How to limit a project within the lines of the page?

Tags: inkscape, page-layout, margin

I would like to know if it is possible to limit my objects and paths within the page size of an Inkscape project. This is, I would like to avoid having objects coming out of the lines of the page...

Can this be done? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you have the document settings to show the page borders? When you can see the page borders, don't place objects and paths in such a way as to extend outside.

Comment: I'm not an Inkscape user, but I'm guessing you could use a mask. But I'm curious why you want to do that?

Comment: Let's say I want to create an illustration to fit a particular screen size. I would set the page size (in px) to that screen size. Hence, whatever comes out of the page would not show in the screen I am targetting... That's why I thought limiting to the page would be a good approach. I'm new to this, so any wisdom is welcomed!

Comment: I am showing the page borders. However, I would like to have an actual visual representation of how the end result would look in the screen I am targetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly possible, but a valid question.

A workaround would be to create a large rectangle, much larger than the page boundaries, then create a rectangle exactly the size of the page (using snapping to page borders), subtract that small rectangle from the larger to create a hole in it, set the fill to white, move it to a dedicated layer at the top level, and lock this layer. Now toggling the visibility of this layer will allow you to see the page only.

Alternatively, draw whatever you want to draw, then group it all, draw a page-size rectangle over it, and clip the group with this rectangle. When making additional changes, don't remove the clip and the group, but simply double click to edit inside this group. This could also work, but might be more fragile.

Maybe a bit cumbersome indeed, but I don't think there is anything better